# DTD validity error

Tags: dtd

I'm studying some SQL and DTD on my own. I'm not used to it too much. While making some exercise I'm running into some problems.
Here is the data : https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/countries.xml
I'm trying to write DTD for that. Here what I wrote:

```
<!ELEMENT countries (country*)>
<!ELEMENT country (city*, population*)>
<!ATTLIST country name (PCDATA) #REQUIRED population (CDATA) #REQUIRED area (CDATA) #REQUIRED >
<!ELEMENT city (name, population) >
<!ELEMENT name ANY>
<!ELEMENT population ANY>
<!ELEMENT language ANY>
<!ATTLIST language percentage CDATA #IMPLIED >
```

There may be some minor errors but the error I constantly get is validity error. For example it says

> Value "Afghanistan" for attribute name of country is not among the enumerated set.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of:

```
<!ATTLIST country name (PCDATA)
```

it thinks that `PCDATA` is a value in an enumeration. Try changing it to `CDATA` (without parentheses)...

```
<!ATTLIST country 
          name CDATA #REQUIRED 
          population CDATA #REQUIRED 
          area CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: @JohnRock - You're very welcome. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark next to it (and/or up-voting it :-))

Comment: @JohnRock - Also, if this is for the stanford db class, feel free to send me an email (it's in my profile) if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!I tried to vote but my reputation isn't sufficient :(

Comment: Do not try to vote, just click the "check mark" or "tick" below the votes. I think you can do it that with any reputation